# Failed to pull image "mcr.microsoft.comoss/calico/pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.18.1 (missing "/")

Tags: azure-aks

**Executive summary**

For several weeks we sporadically see the following error on all of our AKS Kubernetes clusters:

`Failed to pull image "mcr.microsoft.comoss/calico/pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.18.1`

Obviously there is a missing "/" after "mcr.microsoft.com".
The problem started after upgrading the clusters from 1.17 to 1.20.

Where does this spelling error come from? Is there anything WE can do about it?

---

**Some details**

The full error is:

`Failed to pull image "mcr.microsoft.comoss/calico/pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.18.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "mcr.microsoft.comoss/calico/pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.18.1": failed to resolve reference "mcr.microsoft.comoss/calico/pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.18.1": failed to do request: Head https://mcr.microsoft.comoss/v2/calico/pod2daemon-flexvol/manifests/v3.18.1: dial tcp: lookup mcr.microsoft.comoss on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host`

In 50% of the cases the following is logged also:

`Pod 'calico-system/calico-typha-685d454c58-pdqkh' triggered a Warning-Event: 'FailedMount'. Warning Message: Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[typha-ca typha-certs calico-typha-token-424k6], unattached volumes=[typha-ca typha-certs calico-typha-token-424k6]: timed out waiting for the condition`

There seems to be no measurable effect on cluster health apart from the warnings - I see no correlating errors in any services.

We did not find a trigger which causes the behavior. It does not seem to be correlated to any change we do from our side (deployments, scaling, ...).

Also there seems to be no pattern as to the frequency. Sometimes there is no problem for several days and then we have the error pop up 10 times per day.

Another observation is that the calico-kube-controller and several pods were restarted. Replicaset and deployments did not change.

[Restart time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKAB4.png)

Since all the pods of the daemonset are running eventually, the problem seems to be solving itself after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a firewall, and used this link to set it up

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/limit-egress-traffic

If so add HTTP to the mcr.microsoft.com, looks like MS missed the 's' in an update recently

Paul

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for checking in. We did not use the setup you linked above. I am currently in touch with MS support and begin to narrow it down. As soon as I know more, I will post it.